# React.js in subfolder and htaccess

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have backend (Symfony) and frontend (React.js).

```
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(api/.*)$ public/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA,PT]
RewriteRule ^$ /fe/build/ [L]
```

I neeed forward requests beginning by `/api` to `public/index.php`. It's working.
Problem is with frontend. I need other requests forward to `fe/build` folder where `index.html` with all assets.

Now I get content of `fe/build/index.html` but I have problem with loading assets.

In console I have following error:

> static/js/main.97d34693.js NOT FOUND

I think that `static/js/main.97d34693.js` is loading from root folder and not from `fe/build` folder. Somebody know what am I doing bad?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ /fe/build/ [L]
> ```

You are only forwarding requests for the root. If you "need [all] other requests forward to..." then you need to remove the `$` (end-of-string anchor) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ /fe/build/ [L]
```

However, this assumes you have another `.htaccess` file at `/fe/build/.htaccess` containing mod_rewrite directives associated with your frontend/reactjs routing. If not then change the rule to the following instead in order to prevent rewriting requests for itself:

```
RewriteRule !^fe/build/ /fe/build/ [L]
```